# Filling a column with incremental numbers

Tags: mysql

I got an SQL query like this:

```
SELECT o.option_id,v.value,o.sort_order
FROM eav_attribute_option o
INNER JOIN eav_attribute_option_value v
ON o.option_id=v.option_id
WHERE v.store_id=1
AND o.attribute_id=167
ORDER BY v.value;
```

The result is:

```
+-----------+-------+------------+
| option_id | value | sort_order |
+-----------+-------+------------+
|       320 | a     |          1 |
|        64 | b     |          2 |
|       444 | c     |          3 |
|        65 | d     |          3 |
|        66 | m     |          5 |
|        67 | s     |          7 |
|       238 | x     |          5 |
|        68 | z     |          6 |
+-----------+-------+------------+
```

I need to update the sort_order, filling with numbers from 1 to N,
based on the alphabetical order of the value field.
Is it possible with SQL only? The result after should be:

```
+-----------+-------+------------+
| option_id | value | sort_order |
+-----------+-------+------------+
|       320 | a     |          1 |
|        64 | b     |          2 |
|       444 | c     |          3 |
|        65 | d     |          4 |
|        66 | m     |          5 |
|        67 | s     |          6 |
|       238 | x     |          7 |
|        68 | z     |          8 |
+-----------+-------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SET @row_number = 0;

SELECT o.option_id,v.value,o.sort_order, (@row_number:=@row_number + 1) AS NewOrder
FROM eav_attribute_option o
INNER JOIN eav_attribute_option_value v
ON o.option_id=v.option_id
WHERE v.store_id=1
AND attribute_id=167
ORDER BY v.value;
```

The result will be:

```
+-----------+-------+------------+------------+
| option_id | value | sort_order | NewOrder   |
+-----------+-------+------------+------------+
|       320 | a     |          1 |          1 |
|        64 | b     |          2 |          2 |
|       444 | c     |          3 |          3 |
|        65 | d     |          3 |          4 |
|        66 | m     |          5 |          5 |
|        67 | s     |          7 |          6 |
|       238 | x     |          5 |          7 |
|        68 | z     |          6 |          8 |
+-----------+-------+------------+------------+
```

You have just to transform the query to perform update instead of select.